# glacier-cmd upload only returns Archive SHA256 tree hash

Tags: cmd, amazon-glacier

i am fairly new to glacier and have been using amazon-glacier-cmd-interface and when I tried to upload a file to the glacier all went fine and the file got uploaded but on upload glacier-cmd returns only

command used : glacier-cmd upload vaultname file-to-be uploaded

| Archive SHA256 tree hash | 22d89405b88da171b942b416cec76949cf11926abc0c5205a7db0f287dee189d |
|      Uploaded file       |    filenane ime

what i need is the archiveId cant figure it out how to get it on file upload.

Answer (score 0):

`glacier-cmd` should emit this during upload:

```
$ glacier-cmd upload Test /path/SomeFile --description "The file description"
Created archive with ID: EQocIYw9ZmofbWixjD2oKb8faeIg4D1uSi1PxpdyBVy__lDMCWcmXLIzNKBP4ikPH3Ngn4w8ApqCMN7XJqNL7V4sxRzq42Zu74DctpLG9GSPSNjLc1_vorGVk3YqVEdjd2cqnWTdiA
Archive SHA256 hash: e837acd31ee9b04a73fb176f1845695364dfabe019fca17f4097cf80687082c0
```

Comment: no the glacier command only returns
sha256 hash

and i dnt know wether it can be used to get archive id
@Andrew Gaul

Comment: glacier-cmd does not emit the archive ID when uploading a single file.  Please refer to https://github.com/uskudnik/amazon-glacier-cmd-interface/pull/170 which fixes this issue.